Does electron have a way to get information about the printer, including sub-sheet information, paper quantity, etc
ipcMain.handle('getPrinterAsync', async (_, args) => { 
  return this.windowPrint.getWindow().webContents.getPrintersAsync();
})

Does electron have a way to get information about the printer, including sub-sheet information, paper quantity, etc`
